# Add a class via jQuery to a div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a class of "active" to a div when it is clicked using jQuery. Bascially, I want to add a css class of active so that the state button retains a unique color (or the hover class.)

Unfortunately, the class is never added.  I have tried the toggle function as well, and placed the functions in different areas.  I tried bind as well.  Nothing seems to go.  I'm fairly new at this and have looked through similar posts here but was not able to find the answer.

Also, how can I set the default class?  I would like one of the elements to have the 'active' class by default when the page loads and not by click.

Here is the latest of what I have tried:

```js
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
});
jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
jQuery('.div'+$(this).attr('target')).show(); 
});
});
jQuery(".showSingle").click(function(){
jQuery(".showSingle").removeClass("active");
jQuery(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.cool-button-link {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 margin: 15px;
 background: #4479BA;
 color: #FFF;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: solid 1px #20538D;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
 transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -webkit-user-select:none;
 -moz-user-select:none;
 -ms-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
}
.cool-button-link:hover {
 background: #356094;
 border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.cool-button-link:active {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 background: #2E5481;
 border: solid 1px #203E5F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons" style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18pt;"> 
<a class="showSingle cool-button-link" style="color: #ffffff;" target="1" rel="noopener noreferrer" onmouseover="this.style.color='#2ea3f2';"onmouseout="this.style.color='white';">Florida </a>
<a class="showSingle  cool-button-link" style="color: #ffffff;" target="2" rel="noopener noreferrer" onmouseover="this.style.color='#2ea3f2';"onmouseout="this.style.color='white';">Illinois </a>
<a class="showSingle  cool-button-link" style="color: #ffffff;" target="3" rel="noopener noreferrer" onmouseover="this.style.color='#2ea3f2';"onmouseout="this.style.color='white';">Iowa </a>
<a class="showSingle  cool-button-link" style="color: #ffffff;" target="4" rel="noopener noreferrer" onmouseover="this.style.color='#2ea3f2';"onmouseout="this.style.color='white';">Kansas </a>
</span>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv div1">Jacksonville</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv div2">Springfield</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv div3">Des Moines</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv div4">Wichita</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have two click events? I think you should join the logic and use an unique event for the click.

Also, you have an extra closing in the first event.

```
jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    jQuery('.div'+$(this).attr('target')).show(); 
});
jQuery(".showSingle").click(function(){
    jQuery(".showSingle").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: There are actually two functions in the first part, so there was not an extra closing.  However, I appreciate your advice and I combined the click function as you recommended.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me how to set a default class, so that one of the items has the 'active' class when the page loads?

Comment: You can simply add the class attribute to the html tag you want to be the default like: class="active".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are referring to `jQuery(this).addClass("active");`, but the class `.active` doesn't exist in your CSS. So the solution is this:

**CSS**

```
.active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #2E5481;
    border: solid 1px #203E5F;
}
```

In your `jQuery` you are calling a class, that is something else than the pseudo-selector `:active`.